# Can git switch branch without the modification

Tags: git

I have a project which have completed the basic models(at `master`), then I commit them.

Then I create two branchs `user` and `product` using:

```
git checkout -b user
git checkout -b product
git checkout user
```

Then I  add the codes in the `user` branch, but I found that I have to make some changes for the basic models.

Then I switch to `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

But I found that the modification I made in the `user` branch is visible in the working directory now.

How to avoid this? Since the `change to master and modification` will be frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git checkout 
To prepare for working on , switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch.

> Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that
>   they can be committed to the .

source : https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html

**So as a solution** you can use `git stash` or you can use `git commit` - when you come back to original branch do a soft reset `git reset --soft HEAD^` this will rollback your last commit and will not delete files

> --soft Does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do). This leaves all
>   your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put
>   it.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `git stash` command.  You can stash your work on the user branch, then check out the master branch and work on that. After making your commit to the master branch, check out the user branch. `git stash pop` will restore the previous state of the user branch.  You can stash the states of  multiple branches, but it can get confusing.